# Add 1 category more to If_in_category statement

Tags: categories, templates

**Hey everyone, a simple question.**

## Question

I need to add one more category: Events in the if statement along with News which is stated in the code. How can I add it? ***Thank You very much :)***

## Code

```
<?php if (in_category('News')) : ?>
```

Comment: I forgot, I could do an array :) <?php if (in_category(array('News', 'Events'))) : ?>

Comment: If that was your answer, submit it and mark it as such.

Comment: @m0r7if3r will do as soon as 8 hours passes as I don't have enough reputation points :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer :)

```
<?php if (in_category(array('News', 'Events'))) : ?>
```